# Rails - Multi-level relationship models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So, I have my models as follows:

Model1 > Model2 > Model3 > Model4 > Model5

> model1.rb

```
has_many :model2, dependent: true
has_many :model3, through: :model2
has_many :model4, ...?
has_many :model5, ...?
```

How do I tell Rails that Model1 has many Model4 and Model5?

Also, for model4, is it too much if I do this:

```
add_foreign_key :model5, [:model1, :model2, :model3, :model4]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this:

```
has_many :model3, through: :model2
has_many :model4, through: :model3
has_many :model5, through: :model4
```

Try it out and if it works, it works. If it doesn't, try something else.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just tell rails that your model1 has many model4 and 5.

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :model4s
has_many :model5s
end
```

and in the respective models 4 and 5

```
belongs_to :model1
```